# What does the second differential of the marginal rate of capital mean in the 'real world'? What's the explanation?

Tags: microeconomics, marginal, capital

$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial k^2}$

Marginal Rate of Capital means the extra production from adding a unit of capital.
Assume f(x) here means production. What does the second differential mean, if there first is mrk?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of images. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_product_of_capital#Diminishing_marginal_returns) did not help?

Comment: Do you mean the second derivative of production wrt to capital, or the second derivative of the marginal production of capital (which is the third derivative of production wrt to capital)?

Answer (score 0):

It measures the acceleration of change in the production. Or alternatively you can view it as the rate of change of *marginal* production. That is it will tell you how marginal product changes.